# Is there a way to have every scheduled task that is created so that a task always runs before and after

Tags: windows-server-2008

I'm trying to save data to a database before a scheduled task runs and after it has finished running so that I can monitor a number of things.

I can manually add an extra action before and after each task, but I can't guarantee other users will do the same.

Is there some way, for all tasks including new tasks created in the future, to always run these other actions before and after?

I'm using WIN 2008 R2.

Answer (score 1):

Graham,

Yes, that's possible, by adding more than 1 action sets as follows-

```
<Actions Context="Author">
  <Exec>
    <Command>C:\Windows\System32\wscript.exe</Command>
    <Arguments>u:\Scripts\Pre_test.vbs</Arguments>
  </Exec>
  <Exec>
    <Command>C:\Windows\System32\wscript.exe</Command>
    <Arguments>u:\Scripts\test.vbs</Arguments>
  </Exec>
  <Exec>
    <Command>C:\Windows\System32\wscript.exe</Command>
    <Arguments>u:\Scripts\Post_Test.vbs</Arguments>
  </Exec>
</Actions>
```

Let me know if it worked.

Comment: I know I can do that, but that doesn't help me with tasks put on by other people.  I'm looking for some configuration that will add these other tasks automatically.  Anyway, I have resigned myself to the fact that it can't be done.